# echo prints out -e inside script

Tags: bash, echo

when I run it in the terminal (bash)

```
echo -e ."\c"
```

prints out `.` and suppresses the newline.

When I run the following script (all the code)

```
echo -e ."\c"
echo -e ."\c"
```

it prints out `..` and suppresses the newlines.

when I run it inside a script with the shebang (`!#/bin/sh`), it prints out `-e . -e .` and suppresses the newline.

Why? and how can I prevent this?

EDIT:
I want to prevent the `-e`'s from printing out, so my output should be `. .`

Comment: is your shebang line actually `#!/bin/echo`? in that case, it's probably due to the fact that echo is a built-in, and the shebanged file actually executes a binary, which doesn't interpret the -e.

Comment: no, its `#!/bin/sh`, also, the -e tag actually works, but it still prints it out.

Comment: Just clarifying here: what result did you expect to see, and which part are you trying to prevent?

Comment: What is your shebang line? Is it possible the shell being run by the shebang is not BASH?

Comment: then I suggest you show us your script, it makes it easier to spot.

Comment: use /bin/echo instead of simple echo in sh. (notice you use bash in terminal)

Comment: I don't know which echo you're using, but 'echo -e "\c".' shouldn't produce any output at all, the last character must be `\c`, as it suppresses all further output (including the terminating newline which is what you're after).

Comment: @roe.  `echo -e . "\c"` Typo in the question, now fixed.  Also, my script is approx 500 lines long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your script shebang to `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh` and see if it works

Comment: or use /bin/echo if you want leave shebang untouched

Comment: changing /bin/sh is safer since there are things that won't work with sh if used in bash.

Comment: given that I wrote and tested the script using sh, is it possible that something may break while using bash? (it's moot now, since everything works after changing to bash)

Comment: depends on your distribution, /bin/sh may be "aliased" to the old bourne shell, or sometimes to dash, and sometimes to bash, etc. Bash is a superset of bourne, so if you write in bash and bring your script to run bourne, you might have problems. see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29 for reference. Its still best to explicitly specify which shell you are using

Comment: @ghostdog74 A superset of POSIX sh -- not a superset of Bourne; in Bourne, you could run `echo foo ^ cat` and the `^` would act like a pipe, whereas in POSIX, the `^` is an argument to `echo`. (That specific difference is how GNU autoconf tests for pre-POSIX Bourne shells).

Answer (score 2):

you need to give the absolute path to echo if your shebang line is invoking sh.  Or just changes the shebang to use bash.